# How do I set XMLHttpRequest.statusText from ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

When I return a 404 error, the UI wants some custom text for `XMLHttpRequest.statusText`. How do I set this text in an ASP.NET Core middleware component?

(I assume its some sort of response header, but I can't find any information on what exactly the browser is looking for.)

ref https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/statusText

Looks like it was called `HttpResponse.StatusDescription` in ASP.NET, but that's not available in ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is:

```
response.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase = "custom text"
```

Note that there is a warning indicating that this isn't supported by HTTP/2